# LLVM pass for generating object code is giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I'm writing a C-subset compiler using the LLVM C++ API, and using a pass for generating object code as well. But the object code generation step is giving segfault when the source files include an if-else block. Below are the codes I'm using

Compiler code for generating the if-else block

```
llvm::Value *Conditional::generateCode(CodeKit &kit) {
    auto *cond = condition->generateCode(kit);
    if (cond == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    llvm::Function *func = kit.builder.GetInsertBlock()->getParent();
    auto *ifBlock = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(kit.context, "if", func);
    auto *elseBlock = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(kit.context, "else");
    auto *mergeBlock = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(kit.context, "ifelsemerge");

    kit.builder.CreateCondBr(cond, ifBlock, elseBlock);
    kit.builder.SetInsertPoint(ifBlock);
    if (ifstmt != nullptr) {
        kit.symbolTable.enterScope();
        ifstmt->generateCode(kit);
        kit.symbolTable.exitScope();
    }
    kit.builder.CreateBr(mergeBlock);
    ifBlock = kit.builder.GetInsertBlock();

    func->getBasicBlockList().push_back(elseBlock);
    kit.builder.SetInsertPoint(elseBlock);
    if (elsestmt != nullptr) {
        kit.symbolTable.enterScope();
        elsestmt->generateCode(kit);
        kit.symbolTable.exitScope();
    }
    kit.builder.CreateBr(mergeBlock);
    elseBlock = kit.builder.GetInsertBlock();

    func->getBasicBlockList().push_back(mergeBlock);
    kit.builder.SetInsertPoint(mergeBlock);
    return nullptr;
```

Code for generating object code from the llvm module.

```
void emitCode(CodeKit &kit) {
    kit.module.print(llvm::outs(), nullptr);

    auto irFile = "output.bc";
    error_code ec;
    llvm::raw_fd_ostream irFileStream(irFile, ec, llvm::sys::fs::F_None);
    llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile(kit.module, irFileStream);
    irFileStream.flush();

    auto targetTriple = llvm::sys::getDefaultTargetTriple();
    llvm::InitializeAllTargetInfos();
    llvm::InitializeAllTargets();
    llvm::InitializeAllTargetMCs();
    llvm::InitializeAllAsmParsers();
    llvm::InitializeAllAsmPrinters();

    string error;
    auto target = llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(targetTriple, error);
    auto cpu = "generic";
    auto features = "";
    llvm::TargetOptions opt;
    auto rm = llvm::Optional<llvm::Reloc::Model>();
    auto targetMachine =
        target->createTargetMachine(targetTriple, cpu, features, opt, rm);

    kit.module.setDataLayout(targetMachine->createDataLayout());
    kit.module.setTargetTriple(targetTriple);

    auto objectFile = "output.o";
    llvm::raw_fd_ostream objectFileStream(objectFile, ec,
                                          llvm::sys::fs::OF_None);

    llvm::legacy::PassManager pass;
    auto fileType = llvm::CGFT_ObjectFile;
    targetMachine->addPassesToEmitFile(pass, objectFileStream, nullptr,
                                       fileType);
    pass.run(kit.module);
    objectFileStream.flush();
}
```

Source file on which I'm testing at the moment

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Generated IR code

```
; ModuleID = 'bootleg c compiler'
source_filename = "bootleg c compiler"

define i32 @factorial(i32 %n) {
entry:
  %n1 = alloca i32
  store i32 %n, i32* %n1
  %n2 = load i32, i32* %n1
  %"Less or Equal" = icmp sle i32 %n2, 0
  br i1 %"Less or Equal", label %if, label %else

if:                                               ; preds = %entry
  ret i32 1
  br label %ifelsemerge

else:                                             ; preds = %entry
  %n3 = load i32, i32* %n1
  %n4 = load i32, i32* %n1
  %Subtract = sub i32 %n4, 1
  %call = call i32 @factorial(i32 %Subtract)
  %Multiply = mul i32 %n3, %call
  ret i32 %Multiply
  br label %ifelsemerge

ifelsemerge:                                      ; preds = %else, %if
}
```

GDB stack trace of the segfault

```
#0  0x00007ffff4386bc0 in llvm::Instruction::getNumSuccessors() const () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-10.so.1
#1  0x00007ffff4fd643c in llvm::BranchProbabilityInfo::computePostDominatedByUnreachable(llvm::Function const&, llvm::PostDominatorTree*) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-10.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff4fdb175 in llvm::BranchProbabilityInfo::calculate(llvm::Function const&, llvm::LoopInfo const&, llvm::TargetLibraryInfo const*) ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-10.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff4fdb9c4 in llvm::BranchProbabilityInfoWrapperPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-10.so.1
#4  0x00007ffff43a7d76 in llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-10.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff43a7ff3 in llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-10.so.1
#6  0x00007ffff43a84a0 in llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-10.so.1
#7  0x0000555555565b73 in emitCode (kit=...) at c.ast.cpp:88
#8  0x0000555555579957 in generateCode (ast=...) at cc.cpp:25
#9  0x0000555555579a83 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdfe8) at cc.cpp:41
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  ret i32 1
  br label %ifelsemerge
```

is invalid IR, you must have exactly one terminator instruction (e.g. `br` or `ret`) in a `BasicBlock`.  You can avoid this by checking for a terminator instruction before inserting the branch,

```
    if (ifBlock->size() == 0 || !ifBlock->back().isTerminator()) {
        kit.builder.CreateBr(mergeBlock);
    }
    // ...
    if (elseBlock->size() == 0 || !elseBlock->back().isTerminator()) {
        kit.builder.CreateBr(mergeBlock);
    }
```

Note that empty blocks are also invalid so in case both branches of the conditional exit the function, you probably shouldn't generate `mergeBlock`.  AFAIK if you have no branches to an empty block it's fine to leave it in.

---

Usually you can catch these kinds of bugs in your front-end by adding a verification pass or using `llvm::verifyFunction` or `llvm::verifyModule`.  Also running `llc` with the generated IR code will give a more detailed error message.

Comment: Thank you, you are right!! The multiple terminator instructions was the issue. Just a note, your code did not work for me, maybe because I'm using the latest version of LLVM, the `isTerminator` function isn't there anymore seemingly. There's however a simpler way `if (ifBlock->getTerminator() == nullptr) kit.builder.CreateBr(mergeBlock);`. Can you add this as an edit to your answer? I'm using LLVM 12. Otherwise, perfect answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @SkullTech `llvm::Instruction` does have an [`isTerminator`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#a7653277511df1034148a37520a585bb5) member function, I just made a typo in my answer, instead of `->end().isTerminator()` it should be `->back().isTerminator()`.